# HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor Heating Up and Not Working

Tags: pi-4, sensor, electronics, wiring, breadboard

I have two breadboards (for the front and back of a go-kart) which are supplied by the 5V power pins of the raspberry pi 4 respectively (pins 2 and 4). However, when both are plugged in, the second sensor (connected to pin 4) heats up extremely when I boot up the pi. I wired the two sensors identically to their breadboards, the only difference being that they are wired to different VCC, GND pins and the TRIG and ECHO are wired to different gpio pins. Here are some pictures if they help: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cw1IAwGDgNI_b2StyqLrxCsw8L5kJKp7?usp=sharing.(The sensor that is heating up is the second one, on the right if you look at the pictures.) Red is for VCC, black for GND, yellow for ECHO, and blue for TRIG. I'd also like to note that when I used the same ground (34) and VCC (4) pins that I used for the second sensor (the one that is heating up) for the first sensor instead of its original pins (6 and 2 respectively), the first sensor also heats up. It's not a faulty sensor either because I've tried multiple others and still achieved the same result. Thank you, I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please use a breadboard power rail for 5V and ground.  Power all the sensors from that rail. Wire up one sensor first and get that working.  If one doesn't work edit your question and tell us what is wrong.  Please upload photos inline rather than on another site,

Comment: also asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674192/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-heating-up-and-not-working